# Tricky chained API calls with jquery to get information out of them

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, each

Let's say that I have 3 APIs that returns XMLDocuments from an application and I only know "server names", which are my input.

- API 1: gives me all server names and related unique ID for each one of them;
- API 2: gives back all "templates" that a server is assigned with given unique ID; and also gives the "ready to use" URL for the API 3 that...
- API 3: gives every single detailed information about each "template" from API 2;

So, in short, I need to get the unique ID from API 1, passing it to API 2 to get the URL that I need to get all detailed information from the server's assigned templates. And also considering that I may want to get information from **multiple servers** separated by spaces from a input text (and "multiple" servers" is the reason I came here asking for a help... lol). I can't find a way to handle .each loops in order to get a single and final object that contains all the information I need:

```
[
  {
    nodeId: nodeId, // node = server
    nodeName: nodeName,
    aspectProperties: { ...objectWithAllAspectProperties },
    policyProperties: { ...ObjectWithAllPolicyProperties },
  },
]
```

I'm literally getting lost within the loops. If I use a server with 4 templates assigned, and putting the console.log('final data') right before the line "return data;" from main.js (see down below), the console returns arrays at multiple times, incrementing as the loops passes by. And only the last one is the one I need:

```
[object Array][Array[1]]
[object Array][Array[1], Array[1]]
[object Array][Array[1], Array[1]]
[object Array][Array[1], Array[1]]
[object Array][Array[1], Array[1], Array[1]]
[object Array][Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1]]      //////// this is the one I need
```

I'm new in terms of coding, so please don't be rude judging my messy code... lol

So... I wrote 4 js files: main.js, getAllNodeIds.js, getNodeAssignmentList.js and getAssignmentDetailFromURL.js.

**main.js:**

```
import jQuery from "./vendor/jquery-3.5.1.min.js";
window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;

import { ajaxCall as getAllNodeIdsAjaxCall } from "./getFromApi/getAllNodeIds.js";
import { ajaxCall as getNodeAssignmentList } from "./getFromApi/getNodeAssignmentList.js";
import { ajaxCall as getAssignmentDetailFromURL } from "./getFromApi/getAssignmentDetailFromURL.js";

var filteredServersWithIds;

    $("#getXml").click(function () {
  filteredServersWithIds = getAllNodeIdsAjaxCall().then(function (data) {
    var everyNodesAssignmentsAndPolicies = [];

    $.each(data, function (i, jsonObj) {
      $.each(jsonObj, function (key, val) {
        getNodeAssignmentList(val.nodeId).then(function (data) {
          $.each(data, function (i, jsonObj) {
            getAssignmentDetailFromURL(jsonObj["detailedAssignmentURL"])
              .then(function (data) {
                everyNodesAssignmentsAndPolicies.push(data);
                var everyNodesAssignmentsAndPoliciesWithoutEmptyObj = everyNodesAssignmentsAndPolicies.filter(
                  (value) => Object.keys(value).length !== 0
                );
                return everyNodesAssignmentsAndPoliciesWithoutEmptyObj;
              })
              .then(function (data) {
                console.log("final data:");
                console.log(data);
              });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

**getAllNodeIds.js**

```
/* 
The output (return filteredServersWithIds) of the jQuery function ajaxCall below will be:
  [
    { Hostname: "serverone", nodeId: "1" },
    { Hostname: "servertwo", nodeId: "2" },
    { ... }
  ]
*/

import jQuery, { ajax } from "../vendor/jquery-3.5.1.min.js";
window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;

export function ajaxCall() {
  // Defining AJAX settings



var ajaxURL = "http://localhost/api_1/getAllNodesWithIds";
  var ajaxType = "GET";
  var ajaxAcceptedResponseFormat = "text/xml";
  var ajaxAcceptedResponseTxt = "text/plain";
  var ajaxResponseParseMethod = "xml";
  var ajaxContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
  var ajaxAsynchronous = true;
  var ajaxCache = false;
  var ajaxCrossDomain = false;
  var ajaxDataToTarget = null;
  var ajaxUseGlobalHandlers = false;
  var ajaxUsername = "admin";
  var ajaxPassword = "1234";
  var ajaxTimeout = 5000;

  var haveRootNodeTag = "node_list";
  var haveChildNodeTag = "nodes";

  var haveExpectedFormat = 0;
  var haveExpectedResponse = 0;
  var haveNonExpected = "";
  var haveRawResponse = 0;
  var haveRawResponseData = "";

  // Begin AJAX Work



var ajaxreq = $.ajax({
    accepts: {
      //xml: ajaxAcceptedResponseFormat,
      text: ajaxAcceptedResponseTxt,
    }, // Accepted response data
    global: false,
    type: ajaxType,
    contentType: ajaxContentType,
    url: ajaxURL,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader(
        "Authorization",
        "Basic " + btoa(ajaxUsername + ":" + ajaxPassword)
      );
    },
    async: ajaxAsynchronous,
    cache: ajaxCache,
    converters: { "text xml": jQuery.parseXML },
    crossDomain: ajaxCrossDomain,
    //, data: ajaxDataToTarget
    dataType: ajaxResponseParseMethod,
    global: ajaxUseGlobalHandlers,
    ifModified: false,
    username: ajaxUsername,
    password: ajaxPassword,
    timeout: ajaxTimeout,
  })
    .then(function (data) {
      // splits multiple servers separated with spaces from input
      var serversFromInput = splitServers();

  var jsonOfNodesWithIds = [];
  var filteredServersWithIds = [];
  var returnedData;

  // parses the XML response from the API 1

  $(data)
    .find("nodes node")
    .each(function () {
      var nodeId = $(this).find("node > id").text();
      var nodeHostname = $(this).find("node > display_label").text();

      jsonOfNodesWithIds.push({
        nodeId: nodeId,
        Hostname: nodeHostname,
      });
    });

  $.each(serversFromInput, function (index, value) {
    returnedData = $.grep(jsonOfNodesWithIds, function (element, index) {
      return element.Hostname === value;
    });
    filteredServersWithIds.push(returnedData);
  });
  return filteredServersWithIds;
})
.fail(function (data) {
  return (
    "Loading XML data response failed with >> " +
    data.statusText +
    ". Status code >> " +
    data.statusCode
  );
});


return ajaxreq;
}

export function splitServers() {
  var nodeFilter = $("#serverFilter").val();
  return nodeFilter.split(" ");
}
```

**getNodeAssignmentList.js**

```
/* 
The output (return jsonOfNodeWithDetailedAspectURL) of the jQuery function ajaxCall below will be:
  [
    { 
        nodeId: "1",
        assignmentIsEnabled: true, 
        detailedAssignmentURL: "http://localhost/api_2/getNodeAssignmentList/id/1",
    }
    {
        nodeId: "2",
        assignmentIsEnabled: true, 
        detailedAssignmentURL: "http://localhost/api_2/getNodeAssignmentList/id/2",
    }
    { ... }
  ]
*/

import jQuery, { ajax } from "../vendor/jquery-3.5.1.min.js";
window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;

export function ajaxCall(nodeId) {
  // Defining AJAX settings

  var ajaxURL = "http://localhost/api_2/getNodeAssignmentList/id/" + nodeId;
  var ajaxType = "GET";
  var ajaxAcceptedResponseFormat = "text/xml";
  var ajaxAcceptedResponseTxt = "text/plain";
  var ajaxResponseParseMethod = "xml";
  var ajaxContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
  var ajaxAsynchronous = true;
  var ajaxCache = false;
  var ajaxCrossDomain = false;
  var ajaxDataToTarget = null;
  var ajaxUseGlobalHandlers = false;
  var ajaxUsername = "admin";
  var ajaxPassword = "1234";
  var ajaxTimeout = 5000;

  var haveExpectedFormat = 0;
  var haveExpectedResponse = 0;
  var haveNonExpected = "";
  var haveRawResponse = 0;
  var haveRawResponseData = "";

  // Begin AJAX Work

  var ajaxreq = $.ajax({
    accepts: {
      //xml: ajaxAcceptedResponseFormat,
      text: ajaxAcceptedResponseTxt,
    }, // Accepted response data
    global: false,
    type: ajaxType,
    contentType: ajaxContentType,
    url: ajaxURL,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader(
        "Authorization",
        "Basic " + btoa(ajaxUsername + ":" + ajaxPassword)
      );
    },
    async: ajaxAsynchronous,
    cache: ajaxCache,
    converters: { "text xml": jQuery.parseXML },
    crossDomain: ajaxCrossDomain,
    //, data: ajaxDataToTarget
    dataType: ajaxResponseParseMethod,
    global: ajaxUseGlobalHandlers,
    ifModified: false,
    username: ajaxUsername,
    password: ajaxPassword,
    timeout: ajaxTimeout,
  })
    .then(
      function (data) {
        var jsonOfNodeWithDetailedAspectURL = [];

    $(data)
      .find("assignment_list template_version_assignment")
      .each(function () {
        var nodeId = $(this).find("related_ci > target_id").text();
        var assignmentIsEnabled = $(this).find("is_enabled").text();
        var unchangedDetailedAssignmentURL = $(this)
          .find("link[rel=verbose]")
          .attr("href");

        var correctedDetailedAssignmentURL = unchangedDetailedAssignmentURL.replace(
          /clusterapplication:80/,
          "localhost"
        );

        jsonOfNodeWithDetailedAspectURL.push({
          nodeId: nodeId,
          assignmentIsEnabled: assignmentIsEnabled,
          detailedAssignmentURL: correctedDetailedAssignmentURL,
        });
      });

    $(data)
      .find("assignment_list aspect_version_assignment")
      .each(function () {
        var nodeId = $(this).find("related_ci > target_id").text();
        var assignmentIsEnabled = $(this).find("is_enabled").text();
        var unchangedDetailedAssignmentURL = $(this)
          .find("link[rel=verbose]")
          .attr("href");

        var correctedDetailedAssignmentURL = unchangedDetailedAssignmentURL.replace(
          /clusterapplication:80/,
          "localhost"
        );

        jsonOfNodeWithDetailedAspectURL.push({
          nodeId: nodeId,
          assignmentIsEnabled: assignmentIsEnabled,
          detailedAssignmentURL: correctedDetailedAssignmentURL,
        });
      });
    return jsonOfNodeWithDetailedAspectURL;
  } // End function
)
.fail(function (data) {
  return (
    "Loading XML data response failed with >> " +
    data.statusText +
    ". Status code >> " +
    data.statusCode
  );
});  

return ajaxreq;
}
```

**getAssignmentDetailFromURL.js**

```
import jQuery, { ajax } from "../vendor/jquery-3.5.1.min.js";
window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;

export function ajaxCall(nodeDetailedAssignmentURL) {
  // Defining AJAX settings

  var ajaxURL = nodeDetailedAssignmentURL;
  var ajaxType = "GET";
  var ajaxAcceptedResponseFormat = "text/xml";
  var ajaxAcceptedResponseTxt = "text/plain";
  var ajaxResponseParseMethod = "xml";
  var ajaxContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
  var ajaxAsynchronous = true;
  var ajaxCache = false;
  var ajaxCrossDomain = false;
  var ajaxDataToTarget = null;
  var ajaxUseGlobalHandlers = false;
  var ajaxUsername = "admin";
  var ajaxPassword = "1234";
  var ajaxTimeout = 5000;

  var haveExpectedFormat = 0;
  var haveExpectedResponse = 0;
  var haveNonExpected = "";
  var haveRawResponse = 0;
  var haveRawResponseData = "";

  // Begin AJAX Work

  var ajaxreq = $.ajax({
    accepts: {
      //xml: ajaxAcceptedResponseFormat,
      text: ajaxAcceptedResponseTxt,
    }, // Accepted response data
    global: false,
    type: ajaxType,
    contentType: ajaxContentType,
    url: ajaxURL,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader(
        "Authorization",
        "Basic " + btoa(ajaxUsername + ":" + ajaxPassword)
      );
    },
    async: ajaxAsynchronous,
    cache: ajaxCache,
    converters: { "text xml": jQuery.parseXML },
    crossDomain: ajaxCrossDomain,
    //, data: ajaxDataToTarget
    dataType: ajaxResponseParseMethod,
    global: ajaxUseGlobalHandlers,
    ifModified: false,
    username: ajaxUsername,
    password: ajaxPassword,
    timeout: ajaxTimeout,
  })
    .then(
      function (data) {
        var aspectProperties = [];
        var policyProperties = [];
        var objectOfNodeAspectAndPolicies = [];

        $(data)
          .find("aspect_version_assignment")
          .each(function () {

            var aspectIsEnabled = $(this).find("is_enabled").text();
            var aspectTargetId = $(this)
              .find("aspect_version_ref > target_id")
              .text();
            var aspectDisplayLabel = $(this)
              .find("aspect_version_ref > display_label")
              .text();
            var aspectDescription = $(this)
              .find("aspect_version_ref > description")
              .text();
            var aspectMajorVersion = $(this)
              .find("aspect_version_ref > major_version")
              .text();
            var aspectMinorVersion = $(this)
              .find("aspect_version_ref > minor_version")
              .text();


            var nodeId = $(this)
              .find("related_ci > configuration_item > id")
              .text();
            var nodeType = $(this)
              .find("related_ci > configuration_item > type")
              .text();
            var nodeName = $(this)
              .find("related_ci > configuration_item > name")
              .text();

            aspectProperties.push({
              nodeId: nodeId,
              nodeType: nodeType,
              nodeName: nodeName,
              aspectIsEnabled: aspectIsEnabled,
              aspectTargetId: aspectTargetId,
              aspectDisplayLabel: aspectDisplayLabel,
              aspectDescription: aspectDescription,
              aspectMajorVersion: aspectMajorVersion,
              aspectMinorVersion: aspectMinorVersion,
            });


            $(data)
              .find("parameter_value_list parameter_value")
              .each(function () {
                var policyType = $(this)
                  .find("parameter_context > defined_in_type")
                  .text();
                var policyLabel = $(this)
                  .find("parameter_context > defined_in_label")
                  .text();
                var policyDescription = $(this)
                  .find("parameter_context > defined_in_desc")
                  .text();

                var metricId = $(this).find("parameter > id").text();
                var metricDisplayLabel = $(this)
                  .find("parameter > display_label")
                  .text();
                var metricType = $(this).find("parameter > type").text();
                var metricDescription = $(this)
                  .find("parameter > description")
                  .text();
                var metricDefaultValue = $(this)
                  .find("parameter > default_value > value")
                  .text();

                var metricActualValue = $(this)
                  .find("parameter_value > value")
                  .text();

                policyProperties.push({
                  policyType: policyType,
                  policyLabel: policyLabel,
                  policyDescription: policyDescription,
                  metricId: metricId,
                  metricDisplayLabel: metricDisplayLabel,
                  metricType: metricType,
                  metricDescription: metricDescription,
                  metricDefaultValue: metricDefaultValue,
                  metricActualValue: metricActualValue,
                });
              });

            objectOfNodeAspectAndPolicies.push({
              nodeId: nodeId,
              nodeName: nodeName,
              aspectProperties: aspectProperties,
              policyProperties: policyProperties,
            });
          });
        return objectOfNodeAspectAndPolicies;
      } // End function
    )
    .fail(function (data) {
      return (
        "Loading XML data response failed with >> " +
        data.statusText +
        ". Status code >> " +
        data.statusCode
      );
    });
  return ajaxreq;
}
```

Well... wrapping it up, these js codes is giving me what I want, but multiple times. This is messing my html as I append the data.

Sorry for the large sized question, but I wanted to give you as much as information I could.

Thanks in advance and happy coding!!!

Comment: Learn to debug, and debug in small steps, so you understand your code, and especially within loops use debug messages to console to understand what and when is happening..

Comment: Also add actual errors you are receiving. Do not expect blindly that someone here will just write the code for you...this way you do not learn anything and you will be here again in few days/hours. So is not a code writing service

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply, man. So, I did try to debug putting console.log in every return of those ".then", but I could not find which one of them would return me only the last output of array that I need, stepping out of the ".each" statement... I'm trully lost. :(

Comment: For sure! I'm not asking for a fresh code that resolves error, man. I'm not receiving errors... That is not what I said when I asked for help. I'm getting the output that I need, but in multiple times... That is the point. Thanks!

Comment: If no errors, then follow my suggestion of putting console.log debug lines at specific places, so you can follow your code, and see what it does, so you understand it. Once you understand it, you will find why it does multiple outputs :)

Comment: Sure, I'm doing this right now!